# Find directory containing file; execute command in that dir; then delete files

Tags: command-line, find, rm

I want to find all directories (recursively) which contain `.cue` files, execute a command in that directory, then delete all files in that directory with the same prefix as the `.cue` file.

```
find . -name '*.cue' \( -execdir myotherscript.sh \; -execdir [rm ${}%.cue.*] \; \);
```

Obviously with the bit in brackets `[rm...]` not working.

For the deletion bit, if the directory contains a file like `marley-birds.cue`, I want to delete all files of the type `marley-birds.*` (including the `.cue` file itself).

Comment: Each directory will have only one ``.cue`` file. And the script just needs to run once per directory.

Comment: Your 2nd execdir should be `-execdir sh -c 'printf %s\\n "${0%.cue}"*' {} \;` ... replace `printf %s\\n` with `rm` if you're happy with the result... I don't quite get the point of grouping the two execdirs. Why are you doing that ?

Comment: I suppose I don't really need to group them.

Comment: @don_crissti: Worked perfectly. (I actually ended up just making 2 scripts and running each once - to make sure that the first executed correctly before removing files.)

Comment: the 2nd execdir will never run if the 1st fails - just so you know; it's all in the manual; anyway, you could always post an answer and explain what you did.